# Function first_name and last_name coursera

Tags: python, string, function, if-statement

I am stuck with my code on my assestment. I have passed with sufficient score but I dont like to leave any question on fail- for my own learning.
I manaed to get all statements, apart from the last one, where if first and last name are black, the output should be empty. But I am still getting Name - this word shoul dnot be there at all.

Thanks a lot!

```
   # code goes here
 if len(first_name)==0:
   string="Name: "+last_name
   
 elif len(last_name)==0:
   string="Name: "+first_name

 elif len(last_name)==0 and len(first_name)==0:
   string=""    

 else:
   string="Name: "+last_name+", "+first_name

 return string 

print(format_name("Ernest", "Hemingway"))
# Should return the string "Name: Hemingway, Ernest"

print(format_name("", "Madonna"))
# Should return the string "Name: Madonna"

print(format_name("Voltaire", ""))
# Should return the string "Name: Voltaire"

print(format_name("", ""))
# Should return an empty string

Name: Hemingway, Ernest
Name: Madonna
Name: Voltaire
Name:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The if-elif-else statement exits on the first met condition. Therefore you should wisely define the order of conditions

Comment: great thank you. I put last condition on the top and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

##### What's going wrong

It is impossible for you to reach the condition where `len(last_name)==0 and len(first_name)==0:`.

This is because either your first conditional:  `if len(first_name)==0:` or your second conditional: `elif len(last_name)==0:` will always be true before reaching that.

##### An easy fix

The easy solution here is to move that more complex condition as the first one in your if,elif,else chain.

Comment: great thank you. I put last condition on the top and it worked :)